# Is it possible to use client side version of expressjs roure?

Tags: javascript, express, routes

I need to use expressjs like routes on client side to be possible invoke callback function upon specific route like the following:

```
app.get('/dogs', function(req, res, next) {
    // do stuff
});
```

Is there something like for client side?

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing the other day, and I stumbled upon [Page.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js). 
As the author describes it, it's a

> Micro client-side router inspired by the Express router (~1200 bytes)

Plus, the original author is TJ Holowaychuk, the guy behind Express. So I guess Page.js and Express.js should have a few similarities :)

However, TJ posted on his blog about his departure from the Node.js world, so I don't know if he intends to maintain it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clint-side MVC frameworks like [Ember](http://emberjs.com/), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), Bankbone(http://backbonejs.org/) etc?